# Recursive function in pandas

Tags: pandas, recursion

The code mentioned below is working as expected in some cases.

For e.g. this is correct:

```
sandhi_builder('that this')
{'thaxhis'}

sandhi_builder('this that this')
{'thisthaxhis'}

sandhi_builder('bad boy')
{'baaoy', 'bapoy'}
```

But this is not correct:

```
sandhi_builder('this is bad boy sad boy')
{'thisisbaaoysaaoy', 'thisisbaaoysapoy'}
```

There are only 2 strings returned, but expected 4:

```
{'thisisbaaoysaaoy', 'thisisbaaoysapoy',
'thisisbapoysaaoy', 'thisisbapoysapoy'}
```

The code:

```
!echo 't t x' > sandhi_code_out.txt
!echo 'e c y' >> sandhi_code_out.txt
!echo 'e m z' >> sandhi_code_out.txt
!echo 'd b a' >> sandhi_code_out.txt
!echo 'd b p' >> sandhi_code_out.txt

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sandhi_code_out.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

df.columns = ['a', 'b','c']

def _sandhi_builder(my):
    mylist = list()
    for i in my.split():
        mylist.append(i)

    final = list()
    nelist = list()
    check = mylist[0] + ' ' + mylist[1]
    for i in [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
        for p in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
            x = mylist[0][-i:]
            y = mylist[1][:p]
            if len(x) > 0 and len(y) > 0:
                try:
                    z = df[(df['a'] == x) & (df['b'] == y)]['c']
                    if len(z) > 0:
                        for myr in z:
                            myt = [mylist[0][-i:], mylist[1][:p]]
                            final.append(check.replace(' '.join(myt), myr))
                except:
                    pass
    return set(final)
    
    
def sandhi_builder(x):
    sandhi_long=[i for i in x.split()]
    for k, v in enumerate(sandhi_long):
        return_set=_sandhi_builder(sandhi_long[0] + ' ' +sandhi_long[1])
        if return_set:
            pass
        else:            
            return_set = [sandhi_long[0] + sandhi_long[1]]
    for lr in list(range(2, len(sandhi_long))):
        tmp_list = list()
        if return_set:
            for eachv in return_set:
                return_set2 = _sandhi_builder(eachv + ' ' +sandhi_long[lr])
                if return_set2:
                    tmp_list = list(return_set2)
                else:
                    tmp_list.append(eachv + sandhi_long[lr])
        return_set = set(tmp_list)
    return return_set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code lies in the sandhi_builder function. Currently, it only checks the combination of the first two words in the input string (sandhi_long[0] and sandhi_long[1]) and then appends the remaining words one by one. This approach limits the combinations that can be generated.

To fix the issue, you need to modify the sandhi_builder function to iterate through all possible combinations of words in the input string. Here's an updated version of the sandhi_builder function:

```
def sandhi_builder(x):
sandhi_long = x.split()
return_set = set([sandhi_long[0]])  # Initialize with the first word

for lr in range(1, len(sandhi_long)):
    tmp_list = []
    for eachv in return_set:
        return_set2 = _sandhi_builder(eachv + ' ' + sandhi_long[lr])
        if return_set2:
            tmp_list.extend(return_set2)
        else:
            tmp_list.append(eachv + sandhi_long[lr])
    return_set = set(tmp_list)

return return_set
```

This updated version will iterate through each word in the input string (sandhi_long) and generate combinations by calling the _sandhi_builder function. It keeps track of the generated combinations in return_set and appends new combinations to tmp_list for each iteration. Finally, it returns the updated return_set containing all the generated combinations.

With this fix, the code should generate the correct number of combinations for the given input string.

Comment: awesome. Exactly what I was trying to achieve here... https://github.com/shantanuo/sandhi/blob/main/sanskrit_sandhi.ipynb